# Exception extending keras VGG16 model : self.assert_input_compatibility(x) throws

Tags: deep-learning, keras

In order to use a VGG16 network for a regression task, I extend it in the following way:

```
keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False)
        x = model.output
        x = Flatten()(x)
        x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
        x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
        x = Dense(256,activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
        x = Dense(1)(x)
        model = Model(model.input, x)
```

Which immediately throws the following exception:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\GitHub\CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3\model.py", line 116, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\GitHub\CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3\model.py", line 101, in main
    model = create_model()
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Documents\GitHub\CarND-Behavioral-Cloning-P3\model.py", line 60, in create_model
    x = Dense(1024)(x)
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 529, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(x)
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 457, in assert_input_compatibility
    if K.ndim(x) < ndim:
  File "C:\Users\Ralph\Miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 396, in ndim
    dims = x.get_shape()._dims
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Do I have to change the architecture, or is there a problem with the inference of input dimensions?

Comment: what is the shape of the input tensor?

Comment: the original shape is 160, 320, 3  , but the tensor is  resized to 224, 224, 3 during preprocessing. Do you think its the input? the exception occurs at the construction of the network, right in the snippet I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into this; I believe it's a bug in the latest version when you call set_learning_phase; I submitted https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5268 and https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/5269

You can roll back to 1.2.0 as a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
input_tensor = Input((3, 224, 224))
model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, include_top=False)
x = model.output
x = model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(256,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)
model2 = Model(model.input, x)
import numpy as np
model2.predict(np.zeros((1, 3, 224,224)))
```

Output: array([[0.11504173]], dtype=float32)

Comment: Should work for me too, but it doesnt - there must be something wrong with my environment...